# Correct plotting of function involving trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, graphing-functions

I am struggling with how to correctly plot functions $f(x,a)$ involving trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions. Here $x$ denotes the independent variable and $a$ is a parameter. In general, $f(x,a)$ is too complicated to be evaluated analytically, so I am forced to evaluate it numerically.

The problem can be illustrated with the following simplified function:

$f(x,a)=\frac{1}{ax}\sin^{-1}(a\sin x)-1$

where $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$ and $a$ is a parameter. The problem is best illustrated for the special case $a=1$,

$f(x,1)=\frac{1}{x}\sin^{-1}(\sin x)-1$.

Please bear in mind that this is a twice-simplified case (simpler function and special case $a=1$) and that I have to plot more complicated functions by evaluating them numerically. So I am looking for a way to plot $f(x,1)$ numerically.

Now the problem I am struggling with is that $f(x,1)=0$ identically, but numerically this is not the case because $\sin^{-1} x$ always returns a value between $0$ and $\pi/2$. The consequence is that for values $x>\pi/2$ I do not get $f(x,1)=0$.

How can I deal with this problem? The only way I have come up with so far is to check whether $x>\pi/2$ and if that is the case, I make sure that to adjust the value returned by $\sin^{-1}$ to lie in the range $\pi/2$ to $\pi$. Seems easy enough. But it's not clear to me how to extend this treatment to the case where $a\ne 1$ and how to extend this treatment to more complicated cases like

$f(x,a)=\frac{1}{ax}\tan^{-1}(\frac{a\sin x}{a \cos x - a + 1})-1$

Comment: You are looking for the wrong answer. $\sin x$ is a periodic function and so $f(\sin x)$ has to be a periodic function, even if $f(x)=\arcsin x$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't know what to do with it. If you think I'm looking for the wrong answer, can you explain where I'm supposed to look for the right one?

Comment: You are trying to use some terms about functions in a non-standard way. $\arcsin$ is defined on $[-1,1]$ to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, the main branch. You seem to look for some magic extension that from the value of $y=\sin x$ alone selects the correct branch to reconstruct $x$. Which is not possible without knowing $x$. Worse with $y=a\sin x$, there is no way to select the "correct" magic branch.

Comment: In short, the result your computer gives you is, up to the usual limitations of floating point numbers, the correct one, or at least the mathematically sensible one. -- Your assertion that $f(x,1)=0$ overall is wrong, this only holds for $x\in [−π/2,π/2]$.

Comment: You are correct that I'm essentially looking for an extension of the function $\sin^{-1}$ (though I would not call it a magic one). In essence, what I need is for the inverse sine to return arguments in the range $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Then you need also the cosine and the argument function, $\arg(\cos x+i\sin x)$ returns $x$ in the interval $(−π,π]$.

Comment: And it is still magic, since you demand that $\arcsin(y)$ gives two different values depending on something that is not present in $y$.

Answer (score 1):

If I plot $\sin(x)$ and $\arcsin(x)$ for $[-\pi,\pi]$ I get:

[image]

So the expected $\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x$ will only work for $x \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, because outside your $\arcsin$ is not the inverse function.

For $x \in (\pi/2, \pi]$ you should use translations like
$$
f(x) = \pi/2 + \arccos(x)
$$

[image]

The blue curve labeled $g$ is $\sin(x)$ for $x \in [\pi/2, \pi]$.
The black curve labeled $h$ is $\pi/2 + \arccos(\sin(x))$ for $x \in [\pi/2, \pi]$.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to look at the problem. If I take $x=1.8$ as an example, then $\sin 1.8=0.9738$ (to four digits) and $\sin^{-1}0.9738=1.3416$, which of course is correct because $\sin 1.3416=0.9738$ and because $1.8-\pi/2=\pi/2-1.3416=0.2292$. So if I know  $\pi/2\leq x \leq \pi$, I can correct the result of $\sin^{-1}$ to also lie in this range. The problem is that I don't know how to get this to work for the case $a\ne 1$.

Comment: But you want $f(\sin 1.8) = 1.8$ and that $f$ is not $\arcsin$ as it returns $1.3416 \ne 1.8$. While the above $f$ gives $f(\sin(1.8)) = 1.8$.

Comment: But the reason it does not return $1.8$ is not that it is not $\sin^{-1}(0.9738)$, but simply that $1.3416$ is the smallest value of $x$ for which $\sin x=1.3416$. If you take into account the periodicity of $\sin x$, then $x=1.8$ is also correct.

Comment: My impression was you needed $f(x,1) = \frac{x}{x} - 1 = 0$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ and this works only if you use the correct inverses on each sub interval,

Comment: Your impression is correct. And I agree with you that this works only if I use the correct inverses on each subinterval. My understanding is that the reason it does not work is that $y=\sin^{-1}x$ returns the smallest value of $y$ such that $x=\sin y$. For $x/x-1=0$ (as you put it) I need $y=\sin^{-1}x$ to return the next larger value. In the example I gave above, that would be $1.8$ and not $1.3416$.